# XCode Instruments affection FPS with Core Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, instruments

I am developing a game (on iOS in Cocos2d & Box2d). When I debug on my device (iPhone 5), I get between 35 and 50 FPS - but when I use Instruments and profile the Core Animation FPS, its always 60 plus or minus 1 FPS.

Can anyone think of an explanation for this?

Comment: Perhaps you are not using the iphone retina simulator? Perhaps you have not compiled for armv7s architecture?

Comment: @RobertWagstaff I am not using the Simulator at all - both cases are on the device.

Comment: Debug builds are without optimizations from the compiler but release builds (used when instrumenting) have them.

Comment: Fascinating-I believe I am having the opposite effect.  My app seems to show slower FPS in Instruments than when just building to my device.

Comment: @WolfLink Instrumentation also lowers the performance slightly so that could be the reason for what you are seeing (assuming that you do release builds to your device in both cases).

Comment: How are you determining that you have 35-50 FPS when built on device? Are you calculating the time difference and performing an NSLog? That can be a surprisingly expensive operation depending on how it is done

Comment: @RobertWagstaff Cocos2D in built FPS display. (When using Instruments (Core Animation), it matches exactly the FPS shown on the device)